# Probability of a binomial random variable being the maximum of a set of binomial random variables

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, ranking

Let $X, Y, Z$ be independent random Binomial variables, each parametrised with different $p_X, p_Y, p_Z$ but the same $n$. I am interested in a formula for determining the probability that the value of $X$ is the greatest of the three.

A formula for $P(X > Y)$ from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683712/probability-that-binomial-random-variable-is-greater-than-another) is $\sum_{k=0}^n P(X>k)P(Y=k)$. I thought that I could use this like so:

$$
P\left(X = \max_V V\in\{X, Y, Z\}\right) = P(X > Y) \times P(X > Z)
$$

However, when the above is computed for $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, the sum is not 1. What is the error here?

Comment: Your product formula assumes the events $X\gt Y$ and $X \gt Z$ are independent--but they are not.  I found it useful to tabulate the sample space in the case $n=1$ (which has just eight elements) and inspect these events.